# Dependent Select 2 levels

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, html-select

I need help :(

I've got a problem with dependent selects in two levels, I have two selects, one for country and other for city. The problem is that when I selected a country, the select cities shows me a part of my html page, I can't locate where I have the error ...

```js
// JavaScript Document
var  conexion = null;

function crearXMLHttpRequest() {
 var xmlhttp=false;
 try{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 }catch(e){
  try{
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  catch(E){
   if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 }
 return xmlhttp; 
}

//declaramos los dropdowns del documento HTML
var listadoSelects = new Array();
listadoSelects[0] = "pais";
listadoSelects[1] = "ciudad";

/*funcion que devuelve la posicion donde esta el elemento dentro del array*/
function buscar(array, valor){
 var i = 0;
 
 while(array[i]){
  if(array[i] == valor){
   return i;
   i++;
  }
 }
 
 return null;
}

function cargarContenido(idOrigen){
 //cojemos la posicion que ocupa el dropdown que tiene que ser puesto en el array
 var posicionDestino = buscar(listadoSelects,idOrigen)+1;  
 //obtenemos el dropdown que el usuario ha modificado
 var origen = document.getElementById(idOrigen);
 //obtenemos la opcion seleccionada
 var seleccionada = origen.options[origen.selectedIndex].value;
 
 //si el usuario eligio la opcion Elige.. no buscaremos nada en la BBDD
 if(seleccionada == ""){
  var x = posicionDestino;
  var actual = null;
  
  //deshabilitamos las opciones de el select dependiente ya que no hemos seleccionado ningun valor
  while(listadoSelects[x]){
   actual = document.getElementById(listadoSelects[x]);
   actual.length = 0;
   
   var nuevaOpcion = document.createElement("option");
   nuevaOpcion.value = 0;
   nuevaOpcion.innerHTML = "Selecciona una opción..";
   actual.appendChild(nuevaOpcion);
   actual.disabled = true;
   x++;
  }
  
 }else if(idOrigen != listadoSelects[listadoSelects.length-1]){
  var idDestino = listadoSelects[posicionDestino];
  var destino = document.getElementById(idDestino);
  
  var ajax = crearXMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET","action.php?action=dependientes&select="+idDestino+"&option="+seleccionada, true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 1){
     destino.length = 0;
     var nuevaOp = document.createElement("option");
     nuevaOp.value = 0;
     nuevaOp.innerHTML = "Cargando...";
     destino.appendChild(nuevaOp);
     destino.disabled = true;
     
    }if(ajax.readyState == 4){
     destino.parentNode.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
   
  }
  
  ajax.send(null);
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icSquared_v1.0.css"/>
  <title>Información del usuario</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div>
 <div class="registro">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2" style="left:79%; margin-top:2%">
    <?php echo $msgReg; ?>
    <form action="action.php?accion=userRegisterInfo" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <h3 class="text-center" style="font-size:35px"> Datos Personales </h3><br />
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Que eres?</label>
      <?php desplegable_tipoUser(-1); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Apellidos</label>
      <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
      <input type="date" name="fechaNac" required="required" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sexo:</label><br />
      <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="male" checked="checked"/> <i class="fa fa-mars fa-lg"></i> Hombre &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="female" /> <i class="fa fa-venus fa-lg"></i> Mujer 
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pais:</label>
      <?php desplegable_pais(); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Población:</label>
      <select disabled="disabled" name="ciudad" id="ciudad">
       <option value="0">Selecciona una opción..</option>
      </select>
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Imagen de Perfil:</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
      <input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="foto_perfil" required="required">
     </div>   
     <br/>
     <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="enviar" value="Guardar" style="margin-left:40%"/>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/selectsDependientes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you could help me would be a great help.

thanks to all! Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
//connect BD function
function conectar(){
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxx","xxxx");

    //set the language
    $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    return $connect;
}

//disconect BD function
function desconectar($connect){
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

//dropdown tipo usuario
function desplegable_tipoUser($idTUser){
    $conexion = conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TUSUARIO";

    echo '<select name="tusuario">';
    if($resultado = $conexion -> query($sql)){
        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            if($fila[0] == $idTuser){
                echo '<option value="'.$fila[0].'" selected>'.$fila[1].'</option>';
            }else{
                echo '<option value="'.$fila[0].'">'.$fila[1].'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
    desconectar($conexion);
}
```

//dropdown pais
    function desplegable_pais(){
        $conexion = conectar();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM PAIS";

```
    echo '<select name="pais" id="pais" onChange="get_ciudad(this.value);">';
    echo '<option value="0">Elige un País</option>';
    if($resultado=$conexion->query($sql)){
        while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo '<option value="'.$fila[0].'">'.$fila[1].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<p> Error en la conexion o consulta.. </p> <br />';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    desconectar($conexion);
}

//dropdown de las poblaciones
function desplegable_ciudad(){
    $conexion = conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM POBLACION";

    echo '<select name="ciudad" id="ciudad">';
    echo '<option value="0">Elige una poblacion</option>';
    if($resultado = $conexion -> query($sql)){
        while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo '<option value="'.$fila[0].'">'.$fila[2]." - ".$fila[3].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<p> Error en la conexion o consulta.. </p> <br />';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    desconectar($conexion);
}
```

?>

```
<?php 
if($action == "dependientes"){
    $listadoSelects=array(
    "pais"=>"lista_pais",
    "ciudad"=>"lista_ciudad"
    );

    $destino = $_GET['select'];
    $seleccionado = $_GET['option'];

    //funcion que valida que el select enviado por GET exista
    function validar($destino){
        global $listadoSelects;
        $validado = false;

        if(!isset($listadoSelects[$destino])){
            $validado = true;
        }

        return $validado;
    }

    //funcion que valida la opcion seleccionada
    function validarOp($seleccionado){
        $validado = false;

        if(is_numeric($seleccionado)){
            $validado = true;
        }

        return $validado;
    }

    if(validar($destino) && validarOp($seleccionado)){
        $conexion = conectar();

        $sql = "SELECT idPoblacion, nombre,comunidadAut FROM POBLACION WHERE id_pais='".$seleccionado."'";

        if($resultado = $conexion -> query($sql)){
            echo '<select name="'.$destino.'" id="'.$destino.'" onChange="cargarContenido(this.id)">';
            echo '<option value="0">Elige</option>';
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                //$fila[0] = htmlentities($fila[0]);

                echo "<option value='".$fila[0]."'>".$fila[1]." - ".$fila[2]."<option>";
            }
        }
    }
```

?>